# Allow www-data to execute shell script

Tags: linux, nginx, permissions, shell

I have a shell script called boot.sh on an Ngnix server

I am trying to call it via PHP, but I don't think I have permissions.

How can I give www-data permission to run boot.sh - and **only boot.sh**

When trying `sudo chown` or `sudo chgrp` I am getting `Operation Not Permitted`

Comment: Post actual commands and their outputs, plus full paths please

Comment: Is it necessary to run boot.sh as root? What does the script actually do? If the script does not necessarily needs root execution privileges, it's good to simply fix permission of the script for www-data.

Comment: I've done lots of shell execution from webservers (including nginx) and the process executes as whatever user the server is shown as owning by `ps`. Look for password-less sudo. I've done it a few times and there are 2 or 3 ways to pull it off (all hacks). If anything cheat and copy boot.sh where you can get to it?

Answer (score 10):

`system("whoami");` to get the username of the webserver, I use `www-data` in this example.
Edit your sudoers file and add the following. Where `user` is the username it will be run under.

`www-data ALL=(user) NOPASSWD: /path/to/program/or/script`

Then use the following command in PHP.

`system("sudo -u user /path/to/program/or/script");`

Comment: tried with user phpuser. didn't seem to work. tried running the command directly from command line and got: `sudo: unknown user: phpuser`

Comment: It has to be a real user on the system, use the user which you have access to the command line

Comment: Won't the fact that someone is able to run a script as www-data without password create a safety issue?
Will www-data won't be able to run any other commands?

Comment: It will only have `NOPASSWD` for the `/path/to/program/or/script`

Answer (score -2):

Despite the post is from long time ago i would like to recommend this:
run the command 'whoami' from the side-server-scripting language executing the commands lines(php) and then modify the sudoers file with the specific user cause in some cases is www-data an others is daemon .....