# Run a script.sh with www-data like it was root user

Tags: networking, php, debian, exec

I need to get all mac Addresses from my network-card. 
So i use nmap from Debian, combined with PHP.

But, without root privilege, this only gives me the IP address and status from a target. With root privilege, i get IP, status, and adresse MAC.

How i can execute this command (or a `script.sh` with nmap inside), with root privilege and without do a "cracked server" (like `ALL=NOPASSWD`)

Comment: Maybe using a combination of a `sudo` enabled www-data user and a bit of `expect` tooling, but looks to me an XY problem.

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to do? (Because judging by what you're asking you want to create a security hole big enough to drive an aircraft carrier through sideways, and I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume that's ***NOT*** your end goal here.)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, cause i want to search if an other solution exist ... I'm still thinking "www-data ALL=(user) NOPASSWD: /path/to/program/or/script" it's not really a good solution ...
If someone know a real solution to execute a script PHP with root priviliege (or give nmap the same result, regardless user)

Comment: @Hihui if you want to have another solution to the same problem as asked [before](http://serverfault.com/questions/554019/allow-www-data-to-execute-shell-script), then this *is* a duplicate. so what is the underlying problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the MAC-address of a remote IP, you could simply check the ARP-cache, as found in `/proc/net/arp`

```
#!/bin/sh
IP=$1
# make sure that the ARP-cache holds the entry for this IP
ping -c1 "${IP}" 2>&1 >/dev/null
# get the MAC-address
egrep -w "^${IP}" /proc/net/arp | awk '{print $4}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Setuid your script or create sudo rule for it.

Comment: setuid'ing scripts is a very bad practice, as is a sudo rule for the whole script. You should only allow limitied, specific commands.